# Появляются отступы в Chrome на Android

Tags: html, css

Появляются отступы в Chrome[image: отступы][image: как должно быть]

Отступы появляются только тогда, когда на странице есть хотя бы один `<input type="text" />`. Когда input нет, все показывается корректно. На десктопе все отлично, `Html * { min-height:1000000px; }` прописано.

Когда прописываю `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, отступы исчезают, но такой вариант не подходит, нужно чтобы сайт масштабирования во всю ширину сразу при открытии.

Красным выделил блоки, где появляются отступы. На второй картинке установлен `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Стили банальны до безумия. Например, телефон:

```
<div class="header__phone" style="background: red;">Телефон</div>
```

Его стиль:

```
.header__phone {
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
}
.header__phone:before {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
}
```

Стоит только добавить в любое место страницы `<input type="text" />`. И сразу появляются отступы.

Базовые стили сбрасывал, не помогает.

Comment: Не стоит пересоздавать вопросы. Если вам нужно что-то дополнить - редактируйте существующий пост.